# SQL Return Unique Data from 3 columns and how many times it shows up

Tags: sql

What I have:

```
SELECT SGFORM.FFORMDESC, SGFORM.FPAPERNAME, SGFORM.FPAPERDESC
FROM SGFORM
Group by SGFORM.FPAPERNAME, SGFORM.FPAPERDESC, SGFORM.FFORMDESC
Having Count (*) > 0;
```

This gives me a list of the unique items but not the count.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SGFORM.FFORMDESC, SGFORM.FPAPERNAME, SGFORM.FPAPERDESC, COUNT(*)
FROM SGFORM 
Group by SGFORM.FPAPERNAME, SGFORM.FPAPERDESC, SGFORM.FFORMDESC 
Having Count (*) > 0
```